# .htaccess rule for landing page only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building a php framework and at the moment i have these .htaccess rules for directing to my index and getting the controllers and arguments from the URL

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1
```

But since the site is not ready yet I need to add a rule for when accessing root directly to forward to comingsoon.php
any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule before the other one.  This matches www.site.com or www.site.com/

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /commingsoon.php
```

Comment: I added this line and i got 500 internal server error! i restored my old code, restarted Apache even and still getting the same error!! any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Pasted from **Symfony2 Framework** `.htaccess` file (replaced `app.php` with `index.php`) but it should works. Try it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```